# PHP file Download without saving to my directory?

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I have to create one text file and make it downloadable without saving to my directory on button click.
Below I have mentioned code of my file that generate file.

```
<?php
    $data = "ffff dfjdhjf  jhfjhf f f hlm hoejrherueirybgb,nvbd;ihrtmrn.";
    $filename = "SU_Project_Startup.txt";
    $fh = fopen($filename, "w+");
    fwrite($fh, $data, strlen($data));
    fclose($fh);

    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    ob_end_flush();
    echo $data;
    exit();
?>
```

Can you tell me which changes still I have to do in this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely you want that the browser asks where to save the file instead of saving the file blindly? That would actually be a case of the browser configuration, nothing you can do about on server side.

Comment: That means there's a high chance you're using Chrome.

Comment: I think you have to remove this part:`$fh = fopen($filename, "w+");
    fwrite($fh, $data, strlen($data));
    fclose($fh);
`

Comment: @Death That makes no sense..  You want them to download an empty file?(or better yet, one that doesn't exist?)

Comment: @Daedalus  that part writes data to hard disk, `echo $data;`  sends data to user!

Comment: @Death I guess that in my haste I missed that.  Thanks.

Comment: i still dont get any solutions

Comment: Explain more about what you want? did you do what I said?

Answer (score 1):

Try this headers:

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: application/json"); // here is your type
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Comment: i tried this header but it still create one file in my directory

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of taking pictures of the url

you can try it, or put it into function

```
 <?php
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="File-name.jpg"');
    $fileurl = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cc/Ramses_II_at_Kadesh.jpg/120px-Ramses_II_at_Kadesh.jpg';
    $data =  file_get_contents($fileurl);
    echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: i copied the same code and its works fine for image suppose now i want to create text file so what i need to change ?

Comment: have you tried to change the name of the file with the extension txt "filename.txt"